# How to make Fancybox Overlay only affect certain elements

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Standard Fancybox places an overlay on the entire body. Is there a way in the fancybox JS or CSS that I can make it only place the overlay on a certain element of the page?

Thanks
D.

Comment: You can use bigger z-index for elements that you want to be above the overlay.

Comment: Thanks jcubic. I actually want the overlay to appear inside a wrapper and have the popup window also do the same so I don't think z-index would help in this case.

Comment: I did use z-index in the end for some parts of the page but I rewrote the JS to do what i needed it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the following line in `Fancybox.js` as per your requirements

```
overlay.css('height', $(document).height());
```

to

```
 overlay.css('height', $("yourdiv").height());
 overlay.css('height', $("yourdiv").width());
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I rewrote the following section:

```
a.helpers.overlay = {
    overlay: null,
    update: function () {
        var a, c;
        this.overlay.width(0).height(0);
        e.browser.msie ? (a = Math.max(m.documentElement.scrollWidth, m.body.scrollWidth), c = Math.max(m.documentElement.offsetWidth, m.body.offsetWidth), a = a < c ? l.width() : a) : a = q.width();

        var w = $('#page-introduction').width();
        var h = $('#page-introduction').height();

        this.overlay.width(w).height(h)
        $('#fancybox-overlay').offset($('#page-introduction').offset())
    },
    beforeShow: function (b) {
        this.overlay || (b = e.extend(!0, {
            speedIn: "fast",
            closeClick: !0,
            opacity: 1,
            css: {
                background: "black"
            }
        },
        b), this.overlay = e('<div id="fancybox-overlay"></div>').css(b.css).appendTo("body"), this.update(), b.closeClick && this.overlay.bind("click.fb", a.close), l.bind("resize.fb", e.proxy(this.update, this)), this.overlay.fadeTo(b.speedIn, b.opacity))
    },
    onUpdate: function () {
        this.update()
    },
    afterClose: function (a) {
        this.overlay && this.overlay.fadeOut(a.speedOut || 0, function () {
            e(this).remove()
        });
        this.overlay = null
    }
};
```

Where page-introduction is the element I want to be overlaid and the offset of this element is used to offset the overlay.

Robert

Answer (score 0):

i came up with this:

```
helpers:  {
            overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'height': $('.fancyboxwrapper').height(),
                        'width': $('.fancyboxwrapper').width(),
                        'top': $('.fancyboxwrapper').offset().top,
                        'left': $('.fancyboxwrapper').offset().left,
                        'overflow': 'hidden'
                    }
                }
           }
```

this opened the overlay inside the wrapper div and also adjusted the size of the image to the wrappers size.

Answer (score 0):

Find this line in jquery.fancybox.js and change the appendTo to you div of choice, you will need to change the .fancybox-overlay positioning to absolute if you want to position it within that div.

```
this.overlay = $('<div class="fancybox-overlay"></div>').appendTo( ".yourdiv" );
```